# Missing environment variables on running python cronjob in Docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, cron, environment-variables

I'm running a python script inside a docker container using crontab. Also, I set some environment variables (as database host, password, etc.) in `.env` file in the project's directory. If I run the script manually inside the container (`python3 main.py`) everything is working properly. But when the script is run by crontab the environment variables are not found (`None`).
I have the following setup:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get -y install cron
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python-dev

WORKDIR /home/me/theservice
COPY . .

RUN chmod 0644 theservice-cron
RUN touch /var/log/theservice-cron.log

RUN chmod +x run.sh

ENTRYPOINT ./run.sh
```

**run.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

crontab theservice-cron
cron -f
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  theservice:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - ./.env
```

**theservice-cron**

```sh
HOME=/home/me/theservice

* * * * * python3 /home/me/theservice/main.py >> /var/log/theservice-cron.log 2>&1
#* * * * * cd /home/me/theservice && python3 main.py >> /var/log/theservice-cron.log 2>&1
```

I assumed that the cronjob is running in another directory and there the environment variables set in `/home/me/theservice/.env` are not accessible. So I tried to add `HOME=/home/me/theservice` line in the `theservice-cron` file or just to execute `/home/me/theservice` before running the script but it didn't help.

In the python script, I use `os` to access environment variables

```py
import os 

print(os.environ['db_host'])
```

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Cron by default wont load your env variables, have you tried loading them as part of the cron entry like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27291

Comment: @chris-doyle, I added `. /home/me/theservice/.env; ` before `python3` command but it seems didn't help.

Answer (score 9):

I had similar problem.

I did fix it using the following:

```
CMD printenv > /etc/environment && cron && tail -f /var/log/theservice-cron.log
```

According to
https://askubuntu.com/questions/700107/why-do-variables-set-in-my-etc-environment-show-up-in-my-cron-environment, cron reads env vars from /etc/enviroment

Comment: typo: `environment`

Answer (score 3):

For those fighting to get ENV variables from docker-compose into docker, simply have a shell script run at ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile, with

printenv > **/etc/environment**

again, the naming of "/etc/environment" is CRUCIAL !

And then in your crontab, have it call a shell script:

```
* * * * * bash -c "sh /var/www/html/cron_php.sh"
```

The scripts simply does :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html
php whatever.php
```

You will now have the docker-compose environment variables in your php cron application. It took me a full day to figure this out. Hope i save someone's trouble now !

UPDATE:

In Azure Docker (Web app) the mechanism doesn't seem to work. A small tweak is needed:

- In the Dockerfile, in the ENTRYPOINT sh script, write a file (and CHMOD to execution rights chmod 770 )  /etc/environments.sh  using this command:

  eval $(printenv | awk -F= '{print "export " $1"=""""$2""" }' >> /etc/environments.sh)

Then, in your crontab shell where you execute php, do this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
. /etc/environments.sh 
php whatever.php
```

Notice the "." instead of **source**. Even though the Docker container is Linux using bash, source did not do the trick, the . did work.

Note: In my local Windows Docker the first solution, using /etc/envrionment worked fine. I was baffled to find out that on Azure the second fix was needed.